# Value and TYPE in XML PATH

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query to get all the employees firstname in the XML format :

```
SELECT ' ,' +de.Firstname 
              FROM dbo.Employee de
              FOR XML PATH ('')
```

I want to understand what's the difference if I update it to below :

```
  SELECT (SELECT ' ,' +de.Firstname 
              FROM dboDimEmployee de
              FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

What do `TYPE` and `value()` stand for ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TYPE` means the sub query returns a value of `XML` datatype instead of a string.

The `.value` then calls a method on the `XML` datatype to get the value of the element as a string.

The reason why the second one is preferable to the first is in the case that the result of the concatenation contains characters such as `<`. These will appear as desired in the final result and not as raw XML entities such as `&lt;`

```
SELECT 'John' AS Firstname into #TEMP UNION ALL SELECT 'Jack <&>'   

SELECT ' ,' +de.Firstname -- ,John ,Jack &lt;&amp;&gt;
              FROM #TEMP de
              FOR XML PATH ('')


SELECT (SELECT ' ,' +de.Firstname -- ,John ,Jack <&>
              FROM #TEMP de
              FOR XML PATH (''),TYPE).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

The second one behaves the same way as

```
SELECT CAST(',John ,Jack &lt;&amp;&gt;' AS XML).value('.[1]', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)');
```

(By the way if you run these in SSMS you may be surprised that the result of the first one is actually a string as it appears as clickable XML in the gridview but this is due to special casing of the implicit column name `XML_F52E2B61-18A1-11d1-B105-00805F49916B` not the datatype)